# Absolutely positioned outside of AP Parent for mapping

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I am developing a simple mapping application for a client which uses XML, CSS and jQuery. I have the basic functionality working but am a bit stumped by one thing. The "map" is a large image with overflow set to hidden. Then by reading the XML the jQuery places "zones" (`a` tags) on the image positioning them absolutely to the parent map.

This zone the contains two absolutely positioned elements, which need to extend out of their parent. Works exceptionally in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but IE clips anything that goes over the parent. code looks something like the following.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:800px; height:600px;"> 
    <div style="width:1600px; height:1200px; position:relative"><!-- missed out of original post -->
    <div style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:10px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index:10">
        <a href="#" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:80px; width:100px; height:30px; z-index:20">&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="#" style="position:absolute; left:-10px; top:90px; width:10px; height:100px; z-index:30">&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is the clipping normal behaviour or is there something I am missing?

**EDIT: I missed the main map `div` out of the original post.**

Comment: What happens if you remove `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Nothing unfortunately, it still clips!

Comment: What if you put the `position:relative` to the first div ? http://www.jsfiddle.net/KTVPS/2/

Comment: Again tried but didn't work, thanks for the suggestion though. I think I may have narrowed down the problem though, I am using jquery's fadeTo function to show and hide the "zones" on mouseover(out) and when I take this out the map shows as it should without the clipping. Is this something anyone has come across before?

Answer (score 0):

I apologise about this but I have answered my own question. The problem had nothing to do with my css or html it was to do with my javascript.

What I was doing was using the fadeTo function to hide all of the elements on the map, including the zones themselves, then when redrawing the zones and their contained elements IE was clipping the images.

The problem was rectified by removing the fade on the zone div and just fading the inner bits. It now works like a charm.

```
$('div > div > div, div > div > div *').fadeTo('slow', 0);
//this is now
$('div > div > div *').fadeTo('slow', 0);
```

Example applied to above, I'm using classes and id's in the actual code.

Sorry for the waste of time

James